# Ionic + Meteor + App Mobile. How to bind the server?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I have a hybrid application written using Ionic. 
I wanted to integrate an ion-app chat, and I found [this nice tutorial](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic) on how to build a whatsapp clone with Ionic and Meteor.
It's the first time that I use Meteor, but I managed to integrate that chat into my existing mobile application. 
However, I don't get how to bind the client to the server. 
In development mode, everything works since it's all in localhost.
Anyway, I'd like to move the server side to my host domain, while the client side will be build as mobile application. How could I say to the client, that the server is no localhost ?  thank you

sample client code:

EDIT

the code is the same as the tutorial... I have some calls to meteor server like

```
Meteor.call('newMessage', {
      text: self.data.message,
      chatId: $stateParams.chatId,
      userId: CurrentUserService.getUserId()
    });
```

used to save a new message, relative to the chat : chatId

Comment: pls show some code that work on dev machine

Comment: it's not about the code...  it's about the server address...  it assumes automatically that the server is at localhost:3000 ....   but what if I move the server on a remote machine? Where should I put the server address?

Comment: I'm no meteor expert but I think it may have to do with the ROOT_URL value. Try running `ROOT_URL=YOUR_REMOTE_DOMAIN_HERE meteor` when launching meteor. I'm not sure if changing the environment variable will solve your issue. Perhaps someone more adept can provide more insight

Comment: but I guess that variable is server side.... how could  the client know about it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution...  I've just figured out that it works.  Probably, if you are using the full-stack features (like deploy, hot-code push etc.) my solution it's not so safe ...   Anyway, in my index.html I manually set the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL variable to my server address:

```
<!-- meteor -->
    <script src="assets/libs/meteor/meteor-client-side.bundle.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/libs/meteor/angular-meteor-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/meteor/meteor-runtime-config.js"></script>                   
    <script>
       SERVER_URL = "http://my_server_domain:3000";
       __meteor_runtime_config__ = {};
       __meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = SERVER_URL;
    </script>
```

In this way I overwrite the default localhost:3000

(further info [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/develop-and-deploy-server-side-independently-from-client-side-ionic-meteor/21810/10))